Energy in Dielectric Medium as a Sea of Dipoles
Simply, why is the energy density in a dielectric medium = $\frac{1}{2}K\epsilon_oE^2$ where K is the dielectric constant of the dielectric medium?
Working proof
Consider a capacitor that is charged to a potential difference of $V_o$. If its capacitance in air = $C_o$, its capacitance with a dielectric medium filled between the plates is $KC_o$.
Since the energy in a parallel plate capacitor is given by $\frac{CV^2}{2}$ (derived in HC Verma Concepts of Physics using work done in separating two oppositely charged plates to a distance = d), we can say that the energy density in the capacitor with dielectric comes from:
$$u = \frac{U}{Ad} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}\frac{K\epsilon_oA}{d}V_o^2}{Ad} = \frac{1}{2}K\epsilon_oE_{\text{net}}^2$$
I accept this approach of proving energy density in a dielectric medium, and even intuitively, it seems that producing an electric field in a dielectric medium should require more energy than producing the same field in air.
My issue
However, if I view the dielectric medium simply as a sea of small artificial dipoles placed in a specific configuration in empty space, shouldn't $\int\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_oE_{net}^2dV$ be capable of considering all the energy stored in the field?
For any example containing a system of charged particles, I have always learned $\int\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_oE_{net}^2dV$ considers all self energies, the interaction energies summed up. Isn't a dielectric medium just a system of dipoles interacting?
The only possible explanation I could think of for the requirement of extra energy unaccounted by $\int\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_oE_{net}^2dV$ is that the extra energy is not electrostatic in nature, but is still birthed by the existence of a field in the dielectric.
For example, oppositely charged particles held together by a spring, when subjected to an external field, will result in the stretching of the spring, which changes the spring's potential energy not accounted by $\int\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_oE_{net}^2dV$. Then again, even inside the spring, at the molecular scale, the interactions are electrostatic, right?
In conclusion, what is the peculiarity of a dielectric medium's internal interactions that separates it from just a system of dipoles?
here's my previous question on the same topic, which was comparatively poorly framed.

You are not asking exactly the question that I am about to answer, but I think my answer will be precisely answer the essence of your confusion, so here goes:
There is a tremendous difference between the Maxwellian averaged $\vec E$ field as expressed inside a medium, and the true (often called Lorentzian) $\vec E$ field that is actually inside a medium.
If there is no dielectric involved, you have $\vec E=\dfrac Vd$.
Now, consider that the voltage is supplied by a battery and is thus a fixed value. The distance between the capacitor plates can also be arranged to be fixed. Now you insert a dielectric just the correct size for this capacitor. Then, due to the polarisation of the dielectric, inside the dielectric, you have $\vec E_\text{Maxwell}<\dfrac Vd$, ignoring the huge electric fields between the gap between the dielectric and the capacitor gap. Maybe pick a liquid dielectric and so this gap is zero.
This means that when you compute the $\dfrac12\varepsilon_0\vec E^2$ integral, you will get less total energy. This is clearly unacceptable. You know you must have $K>1$ times of that integral.
That energy is actually there because $$\vec E_\text{Lorentz}=\vec E_\text{Maxwell}+\text{mean-zero but wiggles near atomic dipoles}$$ And in the energy computation, this is squared, and so the wiggles contribute to the energy computation, and you have not taken that into account, as long as you were using the Maxwellian smooth averaged fields. You have to use the true wiggly field in order for the simple unadulterated integral to work.

Understood! So there are some deformities in the electric field on the molecular scale, which average to zero when added linearly, so they do not impact macroscopically observed electric field, force, or $- \int E⃗.dx⃗$ . However, since energy shows electric field terms squared, considering these deformities is important. Also, do these wiggles exist before polarisation too?

The wiggles already exist before polarisation; those include the self-energy terms. However, the wiggling changes a slight amount after polarisation to add the bit that is new. It is this bit that is new when you have polarisation, and that contributes to the energy integral.
